# How to print two enhanced for loops next to each other in order

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

If someone could explain to me how you can get these two arrays to print next to each other it would be much appreciated.

```
package labs;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayOfObjects {

public static void main (String[] args){

    String[] pets = {"dog", "cow", "sheep", "cat", "horse"};

    String[] names = {"Spot", "Milky", "Bahhhhd", "Meooooow", "Nayyybor"};

    for (String name : names){
            System.out.println(name.toString());
    }

    for (String type : pets){
            System.out.println(type.toString());
    }
}
}
```

The output i get is obviously

```
Spot 
Milky   
Bahhhhd
Meooooow
Nayyybor
dog
cow
sheep
cat
horse
```

however.... i want

```
Spot dog  
Milky cow
Bahhhhd sheep
Meooooow cat
Nayyybor horse
```

The one thing i did try was to change the two enhanced for loops and use the toString method inside of them and didnt get it to print the array, but when I go to print both of the arrays out in a different for loop the variables i use in the enhanced for loops are not initialized.

Comment: You cannot run two in parallel as you wish. You must use two `Iterator`s

Comment: The problem isn't in the enhanced for loop but rather in your code design that uses parallel arrays. This is yet another reason why you want to avoid using parallel arrays and instead create a class that holds both Strings together.

Comment: Thank you guys i understand, i was just trying to learn and explore the enhanced for loops because I am a beginner

Comment: Parallel arrays were used in the 1960s, in languages like Fortran and BASIC, before languages with data structures became common.  They have no place in modern code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular `for` loop in this case so you can index both of the arrays. You must ensure that both arrays are the same length.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    System.out.println(names[i] + " " + pets[i]);
}
```

I don't much like using parallel arrays like this, as it usually points to a design problem. If you have related data then you should make a class that keeps it together.

Here is a `Pet` class.

```
class Pet {
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Pet(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Now you could iterate over an array (or better, a list) of `Pet`.

```
List<Pet> pets = new LinkedList<Pet>();
pets.add(new Pet("Spot", "dog"));
// add all the pets

for(Pet pet : pets) {
    System.out.println(pet.getName() + " " + pet.getType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below will work BUT only if the arrays are the same size. Another solution you could use is an iterator.

```
package labs;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayOfObjects {

  public static void main (String[] args){

    String[] pets = {"dog", "cow", "sheep", "cat", "horse"};

    String[] names = {"Spot", "Milky", "Bahhhhd", "Meooooow", "Nayyybor"};

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
         System.out.println(names[i] + " " + pets[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] pets = {"dog", "cow", "sheep", "cat", "horse"};

        String[] names = {"Spot", "Milky", "Bahhhhd", "Meooooow", "Nayyybor"};


        for(int i=0; i<pets.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + " " + pets[i]);
        }
    }
```

The output is :

```
Spot dog
Milky cow
Bahhhhd sheep
Meooooow cat
Nayyybor horse
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust the arrays to be the same length so I'd recommend looping through both where **i** will be less than both array's lengths. This ensures you never hit an arrayoutofbound exception

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length && i < pets.length; i++){
        System.out.println(name[i] + " " + pets[i]);
}
```